# Run Bash(.sh) on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, linux, bash, cygwin

This is a GUI java application,
I have a **run.sh** file and I want to run it on Windows 7(x64)
how to made that?

The file have this rows:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -Xmx2048m -classpath ./lib/*: com.jweb2.JWMainWindow  &> out.txt
```

I install JDK, JRE from Java, and Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/)
but did not help anything.

Who knows?

Comment: Why not just write an equivalent batch script?

Comment: What do you mean by it "did not help anything"? That gives little with which to diagnose a problem. But I agree; what's wrong with a batch file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Its just a java command. Convert it to a windows batch (`.bat`) file.**

`run.bat` file should contain.

```
SET CPATH=""
FOR /F %%r in (.\lib\*) DO SET CPATH="%CPATH;%%r"
java -Xmx2048m -classpath %CPATH com.jweb2.JWMainWindow  > out.txt 2>&1
```

It should work if your java command is in `%PATH%`

I dont have access to windows machine right now. So there could be mistakes.

Comment: Are you sure the `java` command supports wildcards in the classpath argument?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if `run.sh` supports it why not `run.bat`? Could you explain your doubts?

Comment: @Shiplu Bash expands the * to matching patterns before passing the command line arguments in to the executable. The DOS shell, iirc, passes in the * and expects the executable to handle expanding it. I assume that's the reasoning behind horse's question.

Comment: @RHSeeger: correct. Windows will not expand that wildcard. I would very much doubt that the batch file will work.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter as it is the last character, but the classpath separator on windows is semicolon not colon as in `\lib\*:`

Comment: That doesn't work - you need to invoke cmd /v and use !CPATH! and remove the /F in the for command unless you're planning on using a command in the ()